# List View on click listener always returns Apple

Tags: android, listview

I set up a listview and an onclick listener from an example I found. The code builds fine and runs. The item number "Position" is correct in the Toast message when clicked but the text always displays "Apple" which is the first string in the array. I think the String text = listText.getText().toString(); line is the issue but all tries fail to correct the problem

```
      public class ElsEditTitles extends Activity {

String[] StrLabels = new String[16]; // Store Label names to string
String StrFile;
ListView TitleslistView;
Context context;
ListView listView;

static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
        "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.els_edit_titles);
    context = this;

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_view_row, R.id.listText, FRUITS);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListClickhandler());

}

private class ListClickhandler implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> Adapter, View view,
            int position, long arg3) {

        TextView listText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listText);
        String text = listText.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(context, text + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }

}
```

els_edit_tiles.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

list_view_row.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

I edited the line by adding the View and it resolved the issue. Thanks prijupaul and egan

```
                TextView listText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listText);
```

Comment: try adapter[position] not position only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the array item for the `position` in `onItemClickListener`. 
Or you can also try changing `findViewById` to `view.findViewById()` so that you get the right list item.

`TextView listText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listText);
  String text = listText.getText().toString();
  Toast.makeText(context, text + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();`

Answer (score 0):

Try to find view by id from incoming view at onItemClick method:
TextView listText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listText);